# What kind of performance should I expect running Emscripten generated code on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, emscripten, asm.js

I am experimenting with using Emscripten generated code in my Javascript application. The results are pretty disappointing performance-wize. I am seeing 40x slower on Chrome 49.0.2623.110 (compiling with emcc -o3) versus a release build on visual studio.

I have a fairly straight forward marching squares based geometry generation function, running in a plain EXE complied with visual studio in release mode, the function call takes around 2.5ms (as reported by QueryPerformanceCounter), the identical function run in my javascript appliction takes 90-100ms (measured by Date().getMilliseconds()). I have verified the time scales roughly with the size of the problem, so it's not just setup/JIT cost.

My compile line is this;
emcc DCEL.cpp MS.cpp Blob.cpp -o html/Blob.js -O3 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_Blobify','_Init']"

I realize there is no native code support on this version of Chrome, but is this expected? Am I missing an optimization step?

Comment: Looks to be a Chrome bug, Firefox is fine: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=601652

Comment: Make sure you don't have the Dev tools open, that may slow down execution in some cases too.